# Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WrongItemTypeException

Tags: wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to access SSRS reports via WCF and it gives me the following error :

```
    Error running report. The operation you are attempting on item '/Reports/Customer' is not allowed for this item type. ---> 
        
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WrongItemTypeException: The operation you are 
        
attempting on item '/Reports/Customer' is not allowed for this item type
```

Can some tell me what mistake I am doing. I am trying to open a report via SSRS WCF on client machine for consuming .

I am using below tutorial :

https://randypaulo.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ssrs-calling-reporting-services-using-wcf-and-using-the-html-output-for-email-notification/

Comment: You can take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/access-report-server-items-using-url-access?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#feedback

Comment: @TheobaldDu The issue was with the paraments which were mentioned was wrong. I just had a look on that and Issue was solved.

Comment: @ShanuGarg please explain your comment. we are experiencing the same symptom.